# Logo is moving when i switch between pages

Tags: css, menu, navigation

i'm working on this website http://tosamaganga.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/

It's really really simple but i've a problem: when i switch between pages everything is okay. But when i switch between "kontakt" page and other pages the logo is moving. Ther's soething wring in the CSS?http://tosamaganga.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/kontakt.html

How can i fix it?

Comment: checked in chrome and firefox, logo is not moving at all, not a bit not an inch

Comment: It's the browsers scrollbar ;-) You can force the scrollbar to always show whether it's needed or not with `html {  overflow-y: scroll; }`, it depends if you think it's a big enough issue to warrant putting a fix in for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nick R said in the comments, it is only the browser's scrollbar. To test this, you can shorten the height of your browser (drag the bottom of the scrollbar up). This will force a scrollbar on the page. The logo lines up perfectly!